# event observer for magento FRONTEND

Tags: magento

i am trying to catch an event that works in frontend scope only , but the event i am observing for this purpose

> "controller_front_init_routers"

only works under global scope not the frontend.
i have tried to find one by printing (inside Mage.php dispatchEvent method) each dispatched event name when page loads but none of those events worked under the frontend scope.
 i need an event that get activated when the frontend page loads.
please advise.

thanks,

Comment: Have you tried : controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after

Comment: @dagfr wow (wth to that) :O i surely did something wrong before , with the event you mentioned. yes this is working under frontend scope. please write it as an answer so i can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To have an event more modulable and more efficient for your task I suggest to use this event :

controller_action_layout_generate_blocks_after

In your function you can do something more precise thanks to :

```
public function yourEvent($event) {
$controller = $event->getAction();
$action = $event->getFullActionName();
if ($action == 'catalog_product_view') //DO SOMETHING SPECIFIC TO PRODUCT PAGE
elseif ($action == 'catalog_category_view') //DO SOMETHING SPECIFIC TO CATEGORY
...
```

Regards,